# Dart web-webui vs angularjs

Tags: angularjs, dart, dart-webui

Still did not get. Why use `angularjs 2.0` with `dart` if dart comes with `dart-webui` with binding and templates and you can annotate whatever you want to be either service (classes), component or whatever.

This is a question.

Answer (score 1):

Because, you are in the middle of a big explosion of technology.

There are many many frameworks and languages being born right now, each of them with their own view of what you need. None of them will have everything you need and must of them will overlap in what they offer. Even technologies from the same vendor.

This is happening in the world of:
Cloud Infrastructure (Azure, Amazon, etc)
UI (Angular, Polymer, Dart, etc)
Storage (SQL, NoSql, Big Data, etc)
and many more ...

It will be up to you to decide what to leverage from what tool if you are using multiples tools that offer the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a good reason to use Angular.**js** 2.0 with Dart because there is also Angular.**dart** 2.0 which is a better fit if you want to use Dart.

Dart web-ui was the predecessor of Polymer.dart. Polymers primary intent is to create reusable web components (build your own HTML tags). Angular is for building complex web applications. Angular has it's own way of building components but it is designed to support Polymer elements or plain web components as well.

Comment: I guess I mean angular.dart 2.0, the angular for dart and dart web ui.

Comment: There is no Dart web ui

Comment: 'web_ui' library (in dart).

Comment: There is no 'web_ui'. See https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/web_ui ("About (deprecated) See the polymer package". (Last updated Jul 31, 2014).

Comment: Ok. no  web_ui no ambiguity then

Comment: You are hard to convince ;-)